# Filtering by int field in serilog table from Azure Data Table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-table-storage, serilog

Hi have one new property in serilog table in Azure Storage Table and i want to filter by it on my solution, i try apply some filter options but with no sucess, with this i get all records from table:

```
var records = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<MyTableDTO>()).ToList();
```

In records i receive a list of array with my field "accountID". How i can apply filters in executequery in my .net-mvc solution? My last try:

```
var queryfiltered = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("AccountID", QueryComparisons.Equal, accountID);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the error and provide a screenshot of your table?

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me which sdk you use?

Comment: Solved with linq: 


    var queryfiltered = mytable.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<TableDTO>()).Where(k=>k.myField==myField);

Comment: @Erased Congratulations that you solve the issue. I help you post it answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. You may mark it as answer or  post it by yourself. Thank you.

Comment: hello @Erased, haven't got you reply. Please don't worry,  you can post and accept(mark) it as answer by yourself. I will delete mine. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations that you solve the issue:

Solved with linq:

`var queryfiltered = mytable.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<TableDTO>()).Where(k=>k.myField==myField);`

I help you post is answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.